# RequestMapping: How to access the "method" value used for a rest endpoint

Tags: java, spring, rest, request-mapping

I have a Spring Boot REST controller endpoint that accepts both GET and POST requests:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value="/users",
        method= {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST},
        headers= {"content-type=application/json"}
        )
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers() {
    if(/*Method is GET*/) {
        System.out.println("This is a GET request response.");
    } else if( /*Method is POST*/) {
        System.out.println("This is a POST request response.");
    }
}
```

If this endpoint is hit with a GET request, I'd like for the controller to execute something in the appropriate if statement.  whereas, if the endpoint is hit with a POST request, I'd like for the controller to take another course of action.

How does one extract this information from a rest controller? I'd rather not have to split this shared endpoint into two different methods. It's seems simple enough, I just can't find any docs on it.

Comment: You could have two different methods, one for POST and one for GET.

Comment: @Kenster That would duplicate code. I would prefer a solution without it, if available.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct approach would be to rather map two separate GET and POST methods, but if you're set on doing this approach you can get the HTTP verb of the request by accessing the HttpServletRequest as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(
    value="/users",
    method= {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST},
    headers= {"content-type=application/json"}
    )
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    if(request.getMethod().equals("GET")) {
        System.out.println("This is a GET request response.");
    } else if(request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
        System.out.println("This is a POST request response.");
    }
}
```

You won't need to change your calling code, as the HttpServletRequest is automatically passed through

Comment: Is there no way to get a RequestMethod object, which is an enum? Is safer to do comparisons than with Strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RequestContextHolder#currentRequestAttributes to acquire the current request.

```
((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getMethod()
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add two different methods with different names, one for the post and another for the get. Also, just leave the desired request method.

**GET**

```
@RequestMapping(
        value="/users",
        method= RequestMethod.GET,
        headers= {"content-type=application/json"}
        )
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers() {
    System.out.println("This is a GET request response.");
}
```

**POST**

```
@RequestMapping(
        value="/users",
        method= RequestMethod.POST,
        headers= {"content-type=application/json"}
        )
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> postUsers() {
    System.out.println("This is a POST request response.");
}
```

This way you don't add additional overhead and the code looks more clean.